# iPhone Dev: Can you have a program running in background respond to SMS in iOS4+?

Tags: iphone

Can you have a program running in background respond to SMS? I basically want my program to sit in the background so the will be iOS4+ and when someone text messages you, the app can then do something with that text.

Can this be done?

I have seen that the question has been asked before, but it was before the iphone could have background apps.

Answer (score 2):

No backgrounding is very limited on IOS. There is only a handful of stuff you can do. You can always send push notifications to get an alert while the app is not running in the foreground.

From Apple:

> OS 4 delivers seven new multitasking services that allow your apps to
>   perform tasks in the background while
>   preserving battery life and
>   performance. These multitasking
>   services include:
>
> **Background audio** - Allows your app to
>   play audio continuously. So customers
>   can listen to your app while they surf
>   the web, play games, and more. Voice
>   over IP - Your VoIP apps can now be
>   even better. Users can now receive
>   VoIP calls and have conversations
>   while using another app. Your users
>   can even receive calls when their
>   phones are locked in their pocket.
>
> **Background location** - Navigation apps
>   can now continue to guide users who
>   are listening to their iPods, or using
>   other apps. iOS 4 also provides a new
>   and battery-efficient way to monitor
>   location when users move between cell
>   towers. This is a great way for your
>   social networking apps to keep track
>   of users and their friends' locations.
>
> **Push notifications** - Receive alerts
>   from your remote servers even when
>   your app isn't running.
>
> **Local notifications** - Your app can now
>   alert users of scheduled events and
>   alarms in the background, no servers
>   required.
>
> **Task finishing** - If your app is in
>   mid-task when your customer leaves it,
>   the app can now keep running to finish
>   the task.
>
> **Fast app switching** - All developers
>   should take advantage of fast app
>   switching, which allows users to leave
>   your app and come right back to where
>   they were when they left - no more
>   having to reload the app.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. The only way for your application to be "called" when it's not already open is by sending a push notification.